# Threshold energy in complex plane

Tags: particle-physics

In studying coupled-channel of $\pi \eta$ and $K\bar{K}$ systems, when calculating $\pi \eta \rightarrow K\bar{K}$ scattering amplitude, the threshold energy is at $s=2 m_{K}$,  where the center of mass momentum is: $q=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{s^2-4m_K^2}$.
 My question is that when we go to the **complex plane** ($s \in \mathbb C$) via unitarizing the amplitude (by the use of analytic continuation) in order to determine pole positions, what should be the condition for this scattering to take place:

$Re(s)>2m_K$   or

$|s|>2m_K$?

Comment: Usually a way to address such a question is to compute something like a measureable probability in which the threshold would be manifest.